# c++ exception specification in a function pointer

Tags: c++, exception

**Code:**

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void foo() throw(char) {throw 'a';}

int main() try {

   void (*pf)() throw(float);
   pf = foo; // This should NOT work 
   pf();

}
catch(const char& c){cout << "Catched ::> " << c << endl;}
```

Why it is possible to pass `foo` to `pf` even though the `foo` exception specification is different from what the function pointer `pf` has ? Is this a bug in my compiler?

Comment: cuz `try-catch` are not part of `function declaration`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**[Exception specifications don’t participate in a function’s type.](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill22.htm)**
Correction:
As pointed out in other answer, it is indeed a compiler bug. It is well known fact that most compilers are buggy in implementing exception specifications. Also, they are deprecated in C++11. So,

Follow Herb Sutter's advice with exception specifications:

> Moral #1: Never write an exception specification.
>
> Moral #2: Except possibly an empty one, but if I were you I’d avoid even that.

Comment: so exception specification in a pointer to a function are just for the client to know that this pointer is pointing to a function that could only throw some specific types. with that being said, you can lie like the example above, and point to a function that throw other types. correct me if Im wrong. thanks

Comment: @AlexDan: Yes, and you must read Herb's excellent GOTW marked inline in the answer.

Comment: Did you read the link you are posted? It says that you cannot use exception spec in typedef, but declared function pointers must have compatible exception specifiers!

Comment: @Als: an Ibm article about Exception specification says the opposite, read the part where it talks about function pointer : http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Ffunction_try_block_handlers.htm

Comment: @AlexDan Exception specifications *participate* the function type. They just cannot be specified in typedefs. So it's your compiler bug. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this is compiler bug. Function pointers must have compatible exception specifiers to be assignable.

Quote from standard:

> **15.4 Exception specifications**
>
> (5) ...A similar restriction applies to assignment to and initialization of pointers to
>   functions, pointers to member functions, and references to functions: the target entity
>   shall allow at least the exceptions allowed by the source value in the assignment or initialization.

**Example:**

```
class A;

void (*pf1)(); // no exception specification
void (*pf2)() throw(A);

pf1 = pf2; // OK: pf1 is less restrictive
pf2 = pf1; // error: pf2 is more restrictive
```

Your code compiled with [Comeau](http://www.comeaucomputing.com/tryitout/) gives `incompatible exception specifications` error:

```
Comeau C/C++ 4.3.10.1 (Oct  6 2008 11:28:09) for ONLINE_EVALUATION_BETA2
Copyright 1988-2008 Comeau Computing.  All rights reserved.
MODE:strict errors C++ C++0x_extensions

"ComeauTest.c", line 9: error: incompatible exception specifications
  pf=foo; // This should NOT work 
    ^
```

As many other people mentioned exception specifications are deprecated in C++11 standard (see Annex D.4) except for `noexcept` specification. So the best practice is (and was)  - **avoid using it**.

Comment: +1 because you certainly seem to be correct, but I'd add the caveat that exception specifications are deprecated in C++11. There are plenty of arguments against them, and it would seem to be sensible to follow Herb Sutter's advice on the matter.

Comment: @Rost: I am becoming a fan! Once again a pinpoint accurate answer. Keep up the good work!

Comment: @MatthieuM. Thanks a lot for good words! I will try to do my best :-)